# Cannot connect to Oracle Database 10g using a C++ CGI with httpd 2.2

Tags: c++, oracle, cgi, apache

I am writing a CGI program in C++. It is supposed to run on version 2.2 of the Apache HTTP Server and it needs to connect to Oracle Database 10g.

I tried to run this CGI program without httpd and it could connect to the Oracle database successfully, but once I ran it through the httpd server it wrote the following message in `error_log`.

> Error while trying to retrieve text for error ORA-12546

How can I solve this problem?

Comment: What OS are you running? If Linux, do you have SELinux? (And if so, anything suspicious in the logs?) Can you log in with sqlplus when you're logged in as your webserver's account?

Comment: Thanks Sathya, it's the SELinux blocks the http service. And I have fixed it according to the log

Answer (score 0):

That generally means that you have encountered an ORA-12546 error, but that your client library doesn't have the actual error messages installed.  That's not a problem, you can search for the error numbers [here](http://www.oracle.com/pls/db102/error_search?search=12546).  In your case, it's "TNS:Permission denied".

Does your CGI user have permission to access tnsnames.ora?

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess, but a common cause for this type of thing is that the ORACLE_HOME environment is not set for your CGI program. Apache usually starts up at boot time ans so skips all the /etc/profile type stuff.

You will need to ensure both `ORACLE_HOME` is set, and depending on your system setup you may also need `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` updated to include `$ORACLE_HOME/lib`. You either need your program to set the environment, or have a `SetEnv` directive in your apache config. Bet way to see if this is the issue is just write a test CGI which dumps all the environment variables.

Now if the CGI is running under `mod_perl` its a bit trickier because mod_perl tends to be pretty anal about environment security. Think we ended up using the Perl*Something*Require directive to set it up within the perl. Sorry for being vague, was years ago....